# $_POST['color'] for VB.NET 2012 MVC 4?

Tags: .net, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Through an input field the color "green" is submitted.

Now, it takes requesting **it**.

In PHP it would be `$_POST['color']`.

I have thought it through, and have gotten it to this code:

---

### The Example:

**The Request for the ColorName - with VB.NET 2012 MVC 4:**

```
    Public Class ColorPrintOutSubmitClassController
        Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

        ' This method will handle GET
        Function PrintOutPage() As ActionResult
            Return View("PrintOutPage")
        End Function

        ' This method will handle POST
        <HttpPost>
        Function ColorPrintOut() As ActionResult
            ' Do something
            Response.Write("You submitted the color: " & Request.QueryString("ColorName") & "<br />")
            Return View()
        End Function
    End Class
```

**The HTML:**

```
    <form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="ColorName" />
    <input type="submit" name="ColorName_SubmitButton" value="Print It Out!" />
</form>
```

---

### The Questions:

The problem in this attempt is that the color name does not get `printed out`, as wanted.

1. Could the problem be rather on `Reponse.Write`, or `Request.QueryString`?
2. How does get the part which is to handle the `GET` - `"invoked"`?

---

***`Invoked`*** = to put into effect or operation
*(Source: The Merriam-Webster Dictionary)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a QueryString, it is the POST itself.  In C# it would just be:

```
Request["ColorName"];
```

So maybe just (not sure, don't know VB):

```
Request("ColorName")
```

But a better way to do this would be to actually bind to a MVC Model

Comment: I will have a closer look to the first part of your writing. With the second part of your writing you seem to be addressing the controller I have used in the example. Where I do think, that the `requesting` may still have to be done with the controller. Yet, I am wondering if you are also referring to something specific - to - Visual Studio 2012? I am using the MVC 4 template, in case anyone is interested.